# Error using 'use client' in Prismic CMS and Nextjs 14 with app router

Tags: next.js, prismic.io

I am building a website using Prismic CMS and Nextjs 14. I followed [this](https://prismic.io/academy/prismic-and-nextjs) tutorial which resulted in a successful website with no errors. On my new project's website, I'm getting an error when trying to import my `<NavBar />` component into my `layout.js` file. My goal with the nav is to conditionally render CSS classes for active and inactive nav links. I don't get this error every time, but when I do, the error is:

[image]

I Googled the error, and I found [this](https://prismic.io/blog/how-to-use-prismic-with-nextjs-app-router) article. I tried putting the `<NavBar />` code directly into my `layout.js` file. The page loaded fine, but I'm still getting that same error from time to time. I think that it has something to do with `useRouter()` and `usePathname()` because the tutorial didn't use that, but I'm not sure. I also read the Nextjs docs regarding client and server components and had trouble understanding.

This is the code from my `layout.js` file:

```
'use client'
import { PrismicPreview, PrismicNextLink, PrismicNextImage } from '@prismicio/next';
import { repositoryName, createClient } from '@/prismicio';
import { usePathname, useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import './globals.css';
// import NavBar from './components/NavBar';
// import Footer from './components/Footer';

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang='en'>
      <body>
        <NavBar />
        {children}
        <PrismicPreview repositoryName={repositoryName} />
        {/* <Footer /> */}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

async function NavBar() {
  const pathname = usePathname();
  const router = useRouter();
  const client = createClient();
  const nav = await client.getSingle('navigation_menu');

  const inactive = 'hover:border-purpleDefault hover:border-b-2';
  const active = 'border-lavender border-b-2';

  return (
    <div className='flex justify-center items-center font-semibold max-w-full mx-auto py-2'>
      <div className='container flex justify-between'>
        <span className='text-2xl leading-6 font-logo flex flex-row items-center'>
          {nav.data.company_name}
          <PrismicNextImage
            field={nav.data.company_logo}
            className='h-20 w-20 ml-4'
          />
        </span>
        <ul className='flex items-center text-2xl'>
          {nav.data.menu_items.map((item) => {
            return (
              <li key={JSON.stringify(item)}>
                <PrismicNextLink
                  field={item.link}
                  className={`no-underline ${(router.pathname = item.link ? active : inactive)}`}
                >
                  {item.label}
                </PrismicNextLink>
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The `<NavBar />` code used in the `layout.js` file is the exact same code that I used when the `<NavBar />` was in the components folder.

This is my folder structure that's relevant to this post:

```
app
|
 —— api
 —— components
|
 —— slice-simulator
globals.css
layout.js
page.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in here is that you're mixing `use client` with a component that uses `await` inside.

`async/await` components are always Server components, which means that you can't mix hooks (which require client components) and `async/await` (which require server components).

Your best solution is to move your `NavBar` component to its own separate file with the `'use client'` directive to allow the use of hooks inside and have the data contained in the `nav` variable to be passed by props.

If you don't want to pollute your `layout` with client fetches you can do something like this:

1. In a file named `NavBarContent.jsx`:

```
'use client';

export default function NavBarContent({ nav }) {
  const pathname = usePathname();
  const router = useRouter();

  const inactive = 'hover:border-purpleDefault hover:border-b-2';
  const active = 'border-lavender border-b-2';

  return (
    <div className='flex justify-center items-center font-semibold max-w-full mx-auto py-2'>
      <div className='container flex justify-between'>
        <span className='text-2xl leading-6 font-logo flex flex-row items-center'>
          {nav.data.company_name}
          <PrismicNextImage
            field={nav.data.company_logo}
            className='h-20 w-20 ml-4'
          />
        </span>
        <ul className='flex items-center text-2xl'>
          {nav.data.menu_items.map((item) => {
            return (
              <li key={JSON.stringify(item)}>
                <PrismicNextLink
                  field={item.link}
                  className={`no-underline ${(router.pathname = item.link ? active : inactive)}`}
                >
                  {item.label}
                </PrismicNextLink>
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

2. In a file named `NavBar.jsx`:

```
export default async function NavBar() {
  const client = createClient();
  const nav = await client.getSingle('navigation_menu');

  return (
    <NavBarContent nav={nav} />
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I'll do the same for my Footer component as well.